# Does SIMBA encrypt the Service Account token in the ODBC connection between Bigquery and Qliksense?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am planning to use SIMBA as the ODBC connection driver between Bigquery and Qliksense.

From what I understand, SIMBA provides mechanism that allow me to complete an OAuth 2.0 authentication flow using a Google service account (by using OAuthMechanism=0). The driver retrieves a token based on the account credentials specified in my DSN or connection string, and then uses the token to authenticate the connection to BigQuery.

For security consideration, I need to make sure that SIMBA will encrypt that token properly. However, in any published documentations, I couldn’t find such information. Can you confirm that such encryption does exist? If yes, could you provide some details or perhaps supporting documents about it?

P.S. I had a previous conversation with SIMBA support on this topic, they suggested me that I should contact Google, as he mentioned "*Google supports their customers on our ODBC driver directly*".